# Hume's Law on the principle of explosion

Tags: logic, hume

The WikiPedia page of Hume's Law stated the following:

> An alternative definition of Hume's law is that "If P implies Q, and Q
> is moral, then P is moral". This interpretation-driven definition
> avoids a loophole with the principle of explosion.

I know that according to the principle of explosion everything follows from a contradiction. Can someone explain me how exactly this alternative definition of Hume's Law avoids a loophole with the principle of explosion? I tried looking this up, but could not find anything.

Comment: See C.Brown, [Two Versions of Hume’s Law (2015)](http://jesp.org/articles/download/two-versions-of-humes-law.pdf)

Comment: I don't understand how does Hume define what is "moral"? it looks like some sort of modus tollens. i.e if P then Q, given ~Q conclude ~P.

Answer (score 1):

Wiki in the footnote refers to: C.Brown, [Two Versions of Hume’s Law (2015)](http://jesp.org/index.php/jesp/article/view/170).

The example seems to be about this "formalization" of Hume's Law:

> "If  implies , and  is moral, then  is moral."

This reading

> "implies that if any sentence is moral then every contradiction is moral, because a contradiction implies everything [this is [Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)], including any moral sentence. So, for example, “Grass is green and grass is not green” is moral. Granted, this is an odd result. Still, I think we can live with counting contradictions as a degenerate case of moral sentences."

IMO, Wiki's comment: "this definition avoids a loophole with the principle of explosion" is wrong. We have problems with exploxion...

Comment: I agree with Mauro's observation that this formulation does not avoid the principle of explosion. If you wish to do that, it would be better to say explicitly, "For a logically contingent , if  implies , and  is moral, then  is moral".